# Windows API: Assign Icon of filetype X to my file

Tags: c#, windows, icons

I've read about [icon handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I am unsure how to work with them.

Let's say I have a C# application (or simply a Windows filesystem object such as a .LNK file) and I want to **assign it the icon, a PDF File currently is using** (or a MS Word file), though the application is not a PDF file itself.

How are icons assigned / where is that association saved? When using tools such as Resource Hacker I can find the icons within application files (of course a PDF file does not have an icon itself). In the registry under HKCR I can find all file types and their respective openers, where are the icons defined? This classifies as multiple questions - I am most interested in how to assign the system's currently assigned filetype icon (e.g. PDF) to my application.

Answer (score 2):

In HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT there will be an entry for the file extension, for example `.pdf`. The string under this key is the name of a file type, in this case `AcroExch.Document`. Look up that key, again in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and you will find either a DefaultIcon or CLSID entry. If it's a CLSID you will need to do one more level of indirection - on my system I end up at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{B801CA65-A1FC-11D0-85AD-444553540000}`. Under the DefaultIcon key you will find the full path to the file containing the icon, and the icon number within the file.

You will need to extract the icon from the file and put it into your application. Note that the icon will be trademarked and/or copyrighted by the company that created it - nobody will come after you if it's for your own personal use, but if you release an application using someone else's icon you could find yourself in trouble.

Comment: Note that the question is not for setting the icon for a file type. It is about setting the icon for the exe itself.

Comment: Note also that using a document icon for your application icon could get you flagged as malware (a trojan horse masquerading as a PDF).

Comment: Interesting take on the malware front, however I would doubt that just using icons would flag the file? I basically will use *.LNK files to link to different types of files. And those LNKs shall have the icons of the respective files (hence the PDF example). But good pointer already!

Comment: *.lnk files take the icon of the target by default, so if that's all you want, then you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

For .LNK files it should be easy. Just right click, "Properties", "Change icon" and in the next dialog "explore". Search the EXE file of e.g. adobe acrobat, the file icon normally sits in the exe file as secondary icon.

For me the path qould be "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
Okay, bad example, the document icon is actually in AcroRd32.dll in the same path, but normally you don't have to search much.